# FutureBuilder rebuilds because of TextField in Flutter making the keyboard disapperar

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am building a Note taking app, basically what happens here is i have a TextField inside a FutureBuilder, so that i can edit the existing note.. The problem is that the FutureBuilder keeps Rebuilding every time i click on the textfield to change the note... and because of that the keyboard keeps disappearing.

```
class CreateUpdateNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateUpdateNoteView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreateUpdateNoteViewState createState() => _CreateUpdateNoteViewState();
}

class _CreateUpdateNoteViewState extends State<CreateUpdateNoteView> {
  CloudNote? _note;
  late final FirebaseCloudStorage _notesService;
  late final TextEditingController _textController;
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = FirebaseCloudStorage();
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _textControllerListener() async {
    final note = _note;
    if (note == null) {
      return;
    }
    final text = _textController.text;
    await _notesService.updateNote(
      documentId: note.documentId,
      text: text,
    );
  }

  void _setupTextControllerListener() {
    _textController.removeListener(_textControllerListener);
    _textController.addListener(_textControllerListener);
  }

  Future<CloudNote> createOrGetExistingNote(BuildContext context) async {
    final widgetNote = context.getArgument<CloudNote>();

    if (widgetNote != null) {
      _note = widgetNote;
      _textController.text = widgetNote.text;
      return widgetNote;
    }

    final existingNote = _note;
    if (existingNote != null) {
      return existingNote;
    }
    final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
    final userId = currentUser.id;
    final newNote = await _notesService.createNewNote(ownerUserId: userId);
    _note = newNote;
    return newNote;
  }

  void _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty() {
    final note = _note;
    if (_textController.text.isEmpty && note != null) {
      _notesService.deleteNote(documentId: note.documentId);
    }
  }

  void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty() async {
    final note = _note;
    final text = _textController.text;
    if (note != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _notesService.updateNote(
        documentId: note.documentId,
        text: text,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty();
    _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty();
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Text('Nuova nota'),
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF52796F),
        elevation: 20,
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final text = _textController.text;
                if (_note == null || text.isEmpty) {
                  await showCannotShareEmptyNoteDialog(context);
                } else {
                  Share.share(text);
                }
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 40,
          right: 25,
          left: 25,
        ),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              Color(0xFFCAD2C5),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: createOrGetExistingNote(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  _setupTextControllerListener();
                  return TextField(
                    controller: _textController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Inzia a scrivere la tua nuova nota...',
                    ),
                  );

                default:
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to keep showing the keyboard in order to edit the current note

Comment: Don't do this: `future: createOrGetExistingNote(context),`.  Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: Thank you so much! After watching the videos I understood and not everything its working fine.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).